# How to set a custom divider to a JSplitPane

Tags: java, swing, customization, divider, jsplitpane

I have found this example :

http://java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document-2/Swing/petersoft-java-style-2/com/petersoft/white/SplitPaneDivider.java.htm

And I would like to apply it to my JSplitPane.

So I do :

```
BasicSplitPaneUI bspUI=(BasicSplitPaneUI)mainContainer.getUI();
mainContainer.setUI(new ola.elementsCustom.SplitPaneDivider(bspUI));
```

But It gives me an error that I don't really understand :

no suitable method found for setUI() (ola.elementsCustom.SplitPaneDivider)
method javax.swing.JSplitPane.setUI(javax.swing.plaf.SplitPaneUI) is not applicable ...

How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 4):

`ola.elementsCustom.SplitPaneDivider` needs to extend `javax.swing.plaf.SplitPaneUI` - are you sure that's the case?

Anyway you can always modify the looks and behaviour of your divider using something like:

```
splitPane.setUI(new BasicSplitPaneUI() {
            public BasicSplitPaneDivider createDefaultDivider() {
                return new BasicSplitPaneDivider(this) {
                    public void setBorder(Border b) {
                        //some code
                    }
                };
            }
        });
```

Comment: @user1012297 technically correct, but nothing anybody wants to do in a real-world application ;-) a) as a minimum, it would be done for _all_ split panes of the application via an appropriate entry in UIManager (vs. doing it on each individual instance) b) extend the delegate of the _real_ LAF (vs. extending BasicXX) c) do it for all LAFs that are supported ...